# load configuration file before app module imports modules

Tags: configuration, angular6

I'm trying to load a configuration file before my app module imports its modules, so i can use the configuration file when app module imports modules.

for now the load of the configuration file occurs at the providers section of the app module, which is loaded after the imports section.

here my code:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {Routes, Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MatGridListModule, MatCardModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import {LayoutModule} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {
  IMqttMessage,
  MqttModule,
  IMqttServiceOptions
} from 'ngx-mqtt';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
import {AppConfigService} from './shared/services/app-config.service';
import {IAppConfig} from '../assets/config/app-config.module';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import * as path from 'path';
import {hostname} from 'os';


export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfigService) {
  console.log('init');
  return () => appConfig.load();
}


export function MqttServiceOptionsConf(): IMqttServiceOptions {
  console.log('init2');

  const appConfiguration = AppConfigService.settings;

  const mqttopt: IMqttServiceOptions = {hostname: appConfiguration.MqttProps['HostName'], port: appConfiguration.MqttProps['Port'], path: '/mqtt'};


  return mqttopt;

}



const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'contactmanager', loadChildren: './contactmanager/contactmanager.module#ContactmanagerModule'},
  {path: 'demo', loadChildren: './demo/demo.module#DemoModule'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'contactmanager'}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MqttModule.forRoot(MqttServiceOptionsConf()),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    LayoutModule,
  ],
  providers: [DatePipe,
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {


}
```

the relevant parts are in the functions initializeApp, MqttServiceOptionsConf , and in the imports , when trying to load the MqttModule and also in the providers when i'm loading my config file.

any ideas how can i solve that issue?

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same issue here!